# python regular expression matches 0 or 1 repetitions

Tags: python, regex

I want to match html headers `<h1> - <h6>` in html with python regular expression. Some of the headers contain **'id'** attribute, and I want to put it into a group.

By trying the following expression I get the one with id attribute.

```
>>>re.findall(r'<h[1-6].*?(id=\".*?\").*?</h[1-6].*?>','<h1>Header1</h1><h2 id="header2">header2</h2>')
['id="header2"']
```

The **question mark** cause the RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of preceding RE. If i put a **?** after the right parenthesis, it will return two empty strings.

```
>>>re.findall(r'<h[1-6].*?(id=\".*?\")?.*?</h[1-6].*?>','<h1>Header1</h1><h2 id="header2">header2</h2>')
['', '']
```

How to use one regular expression to get the following result?

```
['', 'id="header2"']
```

Comment: Try removing the question mark after `(id=\".*?\")` in your second regex.

Comment: First read: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2199958) and then use [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup) :)

Comment: Then it is the same as the first regex, output is `['id="header2"']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool. Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use a HTML parser instead.

The [BeautifulSoup library](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) makes your task trivial:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlsource)

headers = soup.find_all(['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'])
print [h.attrs.get('id', '') for h in headers]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> htmlsource = '<h1>Header1</h1><h2 id="header2">header2</h2>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlsource)
>>> headers = soup.find_all(['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'])
>>> [h.attrs.get('id', '') for h in headers]
['', 'header2']
```

Answer (score 1):

The '.' does not match spaces so you need to explicitly include them.
One possibility would be:

```
>>> re.findall(r'<h[1-6].*?( +id=\".*?\" ?)?.*?</h[1-6].*?>','<h1>Header1</h1><h2 id="header2">header2</h2>')
['', ' id="header2"']
```